# How to run SonarQube on a Linux for z (s390) machine?

Tags: continuous-integration, sonarqube

We'd like to run SonarQube in our Linux for z machine (IBM S/390), but when we unzipped it we found there is no wrapper for that platform.

Is there an alternative way to install it? Maybe building the wrapper ourselves (how)?

Any help from fellow mainframers is highly appreciated! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can give a try to the latest version of the Java Service Wrapper for Linux/z [from the JSWrapper download page](http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/doc/english/download.jsp), but I don't think you will get much support. Moreover, I hope you can install an Oracle (or OpenJDK) JDK on this box, since running SonarQube with the IBM JDK is not supported.